# GroupedData objects in Pyspark 2.4

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql

I have a data in the following format:

```
 +------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+
 |Serial|       respID|     VariableName|            Response|
 +------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+
 |    11|1_10001070394|Respondent.Serial|                  11|
 |    11|1_10001070394|Respondent.Origin|Interviewer Serve...|
 |    11|1_10001070394|              AGE|                  48|
 |    11|1_10001070394|              SEX|                Male|
 |    11|1_10001070394|             Eth1|                  No|
 +------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

I need to convert it to the following format

```
+------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------+---------+-------+
|Serial|       respID|Respondent.Serial|   Respondent.Origin|      AGE|      SEX|   Eth1|
+------+-------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------+---------+-------+
|    11|1_10001070394|               11|Interviewer Serve...|       48|     Male|     No|
```

I am able to do this in python for smaller datasets via the following code -

```py
df.groupby(['respID','Serial']).apply(lambda 
x:x.pivot(columns='VariableName', values='Response')).reset_index(). 
groupby(['respID','Serial']).first()
```

but when I try to use PySpark 2.4 (in DataBricks) it looks like the `GroupedData` object doesn't support the extraction of 1st Not Null value.

I have tried the following

```py
df.groupBy(['respID','Serial']).pivot('VariableName',['Response'])
```

It creates a `GroupedData` object but does not supports conversion to pyspark dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import  expr 
x=File.groupBy("respID","Serial").pivot("VariableName").agg(expr("coalesce(first(Response),'')"))
```

2136 columns is too much in pivot

Comment: Thanks, it works, but creates a list of tuples. Is there a way to convert it to Dataframe?